# IndexError: list index out of range in Disco Diffusion v5.4

Tags: google-colaboratory, index-error, outofrangeexception, stable-diffusion, disco

## **in Disco Diffusion v5.4 after push on "Do the Run!" it write:** *IndexError**: list index out of* range

None
Frame 0 Prompt: ['8k beautiful cyborg with blond hair, intricate, elegant, highly detailed, majestic, digital photography, art by artgerm and ruan jia and greg rutkowski surreal painting gold butterfly filigree']

### Seed used: 1

**IndexError **                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 217>()
216 torch.cuda.empty_cache()
217 try:
--> 218     do_run()
219 except KeyboardInterrupt:
220     pass

1 frames
/content/guided-diffusion/guided_diffusion/gaussian_diffusion.py in ddim_sample_loop_progressive(self, model, shape, noise, clip_denoised, denoised_fn, cond_fn, model_kwargs, device, progress, eta, skip_timesteps, init_image, randomize_class, cond_fn_with_grad, transformation_fn, transformation_percent, inpainting_mode, mask_inpaint, skip_timesteps_orig)
892
893         if init_image is not None:
--> 894             my_t = th.ones([shape[0]], device=device, dtype=th.long) * indices[0]
895             img = self.q_sample(init_image, my_t, img)
896
**
IndexError**: list index out of range

everything is ok, i have not GPU's problem or anothers, but in this section Disco in each series stop and write this msg: **IndexError: list index out of range**

i don't know what must do

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdno0.jpg)